# Get files from previous git commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, version-control, railstutorial.org

Sorry if this question sounds dumb.

So, I am following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial.

Up to the end of chapter 8, everything was work fine.

But I have made some mistakes during chapter 9 that I cannot figure out.

So, I would like to go back to the commit I did at the end of chapter 8, to get everything working again and start over from here.

In other words, I want to erase everything that has been done since that last commit and (re)start fresh at the beginning of chapter 9.

According to the log, here is the commit I need to "retrieve" files from:

```
Computer:microblog TXC$ git log
commit dd0d9e82e802b18e5ba1000eff743445183bcc56
Author: thibaudclement <email@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 24 18:02:13 2015 -0700

    Finish log in/log out
```

I tried to `git checkout` from the current `updating-users` branch and `git delete` the branch, I tried to `git pull` from the remote, and I tried to `git reset hard` to the desired commit (as explained here: [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)), but I could not get my local files to look like the ones at the end of chapter 8.

How can I simply get on my local repository the files from the `Finish log in/log out` commit mentioned above?

Comment: So 'updating-users' is a dedicated branch for chapter 8?

Comment: Also, are you merging everything into master branch after each chapter?

Comment: 'updating-users' is a dedicated branch for chapter 9 (the one I made mistakes in). 'Finish log in/log out' is the last commit I made for chapter 8 (the one where everything was working fine).

Comment: And yes, I am merging everything into master branch at the end of each chapter. I did so at the end of chapter 8, but did not do it yet for chapter 9 (fortunately), as it is not working properly.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for quick response. I'm adding an answer, just go through it, and let me know, if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `git reset --hard commit_id` isn't working, try following:

1. Discard any unstaged changes using:

   `git reset --hard`
2. Checkout to master branch

   `git checkout master`
3. Remove topic branch "updating-users"

   `git branch -D updating-users`
4. Recreate a branch for chapter 9

   `git checkout -b "name-of-the-branch"`

I'm assuming that you're merging your topic branches into master branch, after each chapter.